# Four Pieces Polyomino

Tags: polyomino

[image]

Goal: Create a symmetric polyomino using:

- Two pieces
- Three pieces
- All four pieces

Notes: This is the only set of four different pentominoes which has only one solution with 2, 3 and 4 pieces.

Point symmetry are allowed.

Line symmetry are allowed.

Rotation and reflection are allowed.

But no overlapping.

※This is the source of the puzzle. It's part "Symptomino" [Here is the link!](http://puzzleworld.org/DesignCompetition/2014/)

Comment: Is diagonal symmetry fine, or does it have to be horizontal/vertical symmetry?

Comment: @F1Krazy Either will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP has confirmed that diagonal symmetry is allowed, here's a two-piece solution to get the ball rolling. For convenience, I've coloured each base pentomino a different colour and drawn on the line of symmetry.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second question.

I can't solve the last question.

> [image]

Comment: This implies you found the puzzle elsewhere, rather than having created it yourself. Is that the case? If so, you need to provide a link to the original puzzle.

Comment: @F1Krazy here! It's part "Symptomino"  [link](http://puzzleworld.org/DesignCompetition/2014/)

Comment: If you can edit the link into the question, that'd be great. In the meantime, I'll keep trying to figure out the four-piece polyomino.